# How to calculate the double integral with e and imaginary number?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

How do I write the code for mathmatica to integrate the below function.
it contains e and imaginary i so it is very confusing to me

[image]

Comment: `Integrate[1/Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*E^(I*m*kx), {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: Try going to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), the integral will look much simpler!

Answer (score -2):

Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 10 produces by

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*E^(I*m*kx),{ky,-Infinity, Infinity}, {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi])/Abs[m], m != 0]`

and by

```
Activate[IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][E^(I kx m)/
Sqrt[ kx^2 + ky^2], {ky, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {kx, -\[Infinity], 
\[Infinity]}], {r, \[Theta]}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar"], Unevaluated[Integrate]]
```

> `(2 \[Pi])/Abs[m]`

Unfortunately, both answers are incorrect since the improper integral under consideration diverges. This  becomes clear if we consider the real part of the integrand in polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$, i.e. $\cos(mr\cos(\phi))/r$.

Addition. As Andrew Lewis pointed out in his feedback to [CASE:5002728] , Mathematica calculates an iterated integral, not the double integral. The command

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2]*E^(I*m*kx), {kx,-Infinity,Infinity},{ky,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

says the integral diverges. Since iterated integrals differ, the double integral under consideration diverges.

Comment: A bug report [CASE:5002728] has been submitted by me.

Comment: What is incorrect in my answer?

Comment: I downvoted because your comment about the divergence of the integral is incorrect. This integral converges just fine, you forgot to take the Jacobian into consideration.

Comment: @Roman:  You are not right. If  we take into account th Jacobian, we have $$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^\infty \cos(mr\cos(\phi)) \,drd\phi$$ which diverges.

Comment: That bug is confirmed by WTS.